# How to implement MEKA command in java

Tags: java

```
The command line is:
java meka.classifiers.multilabel.BR \
-t data/Music_train.arff \
-T data/Music_test.arff \
-W weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes
```

I have known how to use command line for Meka, But I could not find the Meka API. The question is how to realize above command line in java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement MEKA command in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492803/how-to-implement-meka-command-in-java)

Comment: I have no idea why this question was migrated from stats.stackexchange.com. Do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: No, I haven't worked with this technology before, sorry.